# How to create new Image in ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

How do I create a new Image in ClojureScript?

I want the equivalent of new Image(); in JavaScript

I have tried 
(new Image)
(Image. )

What am I missing?

Answer (score 15):

You need to qualify `Image` with the `js` "magic namespace":

```
(js/Image.)
```

Comment: You can also use `(def img (js/document.createElement "img"))`